# angular 11 does not navigate inside subscribe

Tags: angular, angular-router, msal.js

The problem is that I can't get redirected (URL changes content doesn't)

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: MsalService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const self = this;
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount() != null) {
        let redirectUrl = params['redirectUrl'];
        if(redirectUrl !== undefined) {
          self.router.navigateByUrl('/activate');
          return true; 
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

but this code works, why?
router.navigateByUrl('/activate') is outside of subscribe

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const self = this;
    
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/activate');
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount() != null) {
        let redirectUrl = params['redirectUrl'];
        if(redirectUrl !== undefined) {
          self.router.navigateByUrl('/activate');
          return true; 
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I really would need the redirectUrl and not like now hardcoded

Comment: what is `this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount()` doing? can you confirm that your code is getting past this condition? is this returning an observable that needs to be subscribed to?

Comment: @Edward yes it does, I've put a breakpoint on return true;

Comment: Have you sorted this ? If so can you post your answer please.

Comment: @Illep due to time pressure, I couldn't spend more time on that, and from what I can remember I reverted the angular version to 10 and it worked. It was something strange like that; if you have a similar problem let me know maybe we can figure it out